# Am trying to change my insert query to bulk insert, how do i do that?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to change the query below on Mysql, the query it's self it's a normal insert query and it takes time to run.What i want is to change it to Bulk-Insert query. I have been reading about bulk insert but am still struggling on how i can change my query.

Bulk-Insert is new to me and am required to use it.I've tried to read about it but can't implement it,and the below query takes time to run.

```
insert into dbo.WaR
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY (M_Prod_full, ''SELECT CODE,OPERATOR_C
where (group like ''''SM%'''' or DN like ''''088%'''')
and type = ''''S'''' and type_R = ''''O''''
and to_char(date, ''''YYYYMM'''') = ''''' + @YM + ''''''')
```

I am expecting a way to implement a bulk insert in my code i provided and i want the bulk insert to reduce the time it takes to run.

Comment: CAn someone please edit my query, am sorry to send it like that.Apologies to the community

Comment: You can switch to `MYiSAM` for faster insertion. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16405)

Comment: i don't see any example of bulk insert o that link

Comment: The above link provides the information for fast insertion for you query. using the query you have and changing storage to `MYISAM` can results in much master quries than `innoDB`.

Comment: dbo.WaR makes me think a sqlserver tag would be better than mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon true it's sqlserver